# iOS Core Data "Views"

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I have a bunch of entities in Core Data and I'm looking for a way to link them together into what I think is called a "View" in Sqlite for easy access.

For example...

**Table 1: "Events"**

- EventId
- VenueId
- ArtistId

**Table 2: "Venues"**

- VenueId
- Name
- City

**Table 3: "Artists"**

- ArtistId
- Name
- Genre

**Views: "MyEvents"**

- EventId
- ArtistName
- ArtistGenre
- VenueName
- VenueCity
- isRegistered *(property within table - doesn't fetch)*

When I create a row to "MyEvents" with the EventId, it should fetch the data from the "Artist" table and the "Venue" table that correspond to that EventId.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is "Relationships".

Check out [Apple's documentation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/articles/cdRelationships.html&ei=He3lUtOMJKTksATOhYKQBQ&usg=AFQjCNHoNeL474rdy9H-G6u-ngeuCXft0g) or this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14742/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-how-to-work-with-relations-and-predicates).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no concept of a "View" in core data. There aren't really "Tables" either. Every records is an, "Entity" - which is essentially a Row in the "That Entity" table. And each "Entity" has attributes (Columns). Entities can have a "Relationship" (Foreign Key) based on their "Attributes" (Columns). When you perform a fetch a relationship behaves like a join.

To get the behavior you want you would have to add foreign keys or make add entities to relate your entities together: e.g. relate the "Events" and "Venues" entities by having an "EventVenueRelationship" entity with attributes "EventId" and "VenueId" and corresponding relationships.

I'm working on a similar problem at the moment where I have a db structure which is very federated and works great on the server, but is ridiculous when you try to shoehorn it into CD. Did you find a better way to solve this?